# Extract a dplyr tbl column as a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, collect

Is there a more succinct way to get one column of a dplyr tbl as a vector, from a tbl with database back-end (i.e. the data frame/table can't be subset directly)?

```
require(dplyr)
db <- src_sqlite(tempfile(), create = TRUE)
iris2 <- copy_to(db, iris)
iris2$Species
# NULL
```

That would have been too easy, so

```
collect(select(iris2, Species))[, 1]
# [1] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"  etc.
```

But it seems a bit clumsy.

Comment: is `collect(iris2)$Species` less clumsy?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

With dplyr >= 0.7.0, you can use `pull()` to get a vector from a `tbl`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
db <- src_sqlite(tempfile(), create = TRUE)
iris2 <- copy_to(db, iris)
vec <- pull(iris2, Species)
head(vec)
#> [1] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa"
```

Answer (score 126):

As per the comment from @nacnudus, it looks like a `pull` function was implemented in dplyr 0.6:

```
iris2 %>% pull(Species)
```

---

For older versions of dplyr, here's a neat function to make pulling out a column a bit nicer (easier to type, and easier to read):

```
pull <- function(x,y) {x[,if(is.name(substitute(y))) deparse(substitute(y)) else y, drop = FALSE][[1]]}
```

This lets you do either of these:

```
iris2 %>% pull('Species')
iris2 %>% pull(Species)
iris2 %>% pull(5)
```

Resulting in...

```
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

And it also works fine with data frames:

```
> mtcars %>% pull(5)
 [1] 3.90 3.90 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 3.92 3.07 3.07 3.07 2.93 3.00 3.23 4.08 4.93 4.22 3.70 2.76 3.15 3.73 3.08 4.08 4.43
[28] 3.77 4.22 3.62 3.54 4.11
```

---

A nice way to do this in v0.2 of `dplyr`:

```
iris2 %>% select(Species) %>% collect %>% .[[5]]
```

Or if you prefer:

```
iris2 %>% select(Species) %>% collect %>% .[["Species"]]
```

Or if your table isn't too big, simply...

```
iris2 %>% collect %>% .[["Species"]]
```

Comment: I like your pull function. I'd just add one simplification for cases where there's only one variable: `pull <- function(x, y) {
  if (ncol(x) == 1) y <- 1 else y
  x[ , if (is.name(substitute(y))) deparse(substitute(y)) else y, drop = FALSE][[1]]
}` so you can go with `iris2 %>% pull()`

Comment: You can also use the `magrittr` exposition operator (`%$%`) to pull a vector from a data frame. i.e. `iris2 %>% select(Species) %>% collect() %$% Species`.

Comment: @Luke1018 you should create an answer out of this comment

Comment: `pull()` will be implemented in dplyr version 0.6 https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/0b9aabf6c06c9cd3b784b155044d497d4b93df3e

Answer (score 86):

You can also use `unlist` which I find easier to read because you do not need to repeat the name of the column or specify the index.

```
iris2 %>% select(Species) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This seems the most versatile method as it works identically with vectors and data.frames, i.e. it enables functions to be more agnostic.

Comment: I was just looking for an answer to this exact question and `unlist` is precisely what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: `unlist` can also extract values from multiple columns (combining all values into a single vector), while `dplyr::pull` is limited to a single column.

Answer (score 23):

I would use the `extract2` convenience function from `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

iris2 %>%
  select(Species) %>%
  extract2(1)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `collect()` between `select` and `extract2`?

Comment: `use_series(Species)` is perhaps even more readable.  Thanks for alerting me to these functions, there are several other handy ones where that came from.

Answer (score 22):

I'd probably write:

```
collect(select(iris2, Species))[[1]]
```

Since dplyr is designed for working with tbls of data, there's no better way to get a single column of data.

Comment: Can't say fairer than that.  It arose interactively in the console when I tried using unique(table$column) to check for spurious values.

Comment: @nacnudus for that case you could also do `group_by(column) %.% tally()`

Comment: An argument `drop = TRUE` to `dplyr::select` would be amazing for the quite many use cases where we actually need to extract the vectors.

Comment: This was the only way I could get a column out of my Sparklyr sdf. Pull wasn't working for me on version 0.7.8.

Answer (score 17):

@Luke1018 proposed this solution in one of the comments:

> You can also use the `magrittr` exposition operator (`%$%`) to pull a vector from a data frame.

For example:

```
iris2 %>% select(Species) %>% collect() %$% Species
```

I thought it deserved its own answer.

Comment: I was looking for this.

Comment: How would I do this if I want to pass not the colname itself but a string variable that contains it?

Comment: @mzuba `tibble(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10]) %>% select_("x") %>% unlist()` and you could also add another `%>% unname()` at the end if you want, but for my purposes I haven't found that last pipe chain link to be necessary. You could also specify `use.names = FALSE` in the `unlist()` command, which does the same thing as also adding `unname()` onto the pipe chain.

Comment: @mzuba I would use the `pull` command now. My solution was written prior to `dplyr` version 0.6.

Comment: Note that `%$%` works on any list, whereas `pull()` doesn't

Answer (score 8):

If you are used to using square brackets for indexing, another option is to just to wrap the usual indexing approach in a call to [deframe()](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/enframe.html), e.g.:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris2 <- as_tibble(iris)

# using column name
deframe(iris2[, 'Sepal.Length'])

# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4

# using column number
deframe(iris2[, 1])

# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
```

That and [pull()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) are both pretty good ways of getting a tibble column.

Answer (score 1):

Another faster way to extract a column as a vector is
convert dataframe to list using c() function and then:

```
c(iris)$Species
c(iris)$Sepal.Length
```

Column to vector using a dplyr approach:

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
         as.matrix() %>% 
         as.vector()
```

In case you want All the values of the dataset
as a vector you simply do:

```
# I have this tibble:
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% head(3)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
```

Do this for column values order (5.1, 4.9 ,4.7,...):

```
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% as.matrix %>% as.vector()

  [1] "5.1"        "4.9"        "4.7"       
  [4] "4.6"        "5.0"        "5.4"       
  [7] "4.6"        "5.0"        "4.4"       
 [10] "4.9"        "5.4"        "4.8" 
 ....
[742] "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica" 
[745] "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica" 
[748] "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"
```

And do this for row values order (5.1, 3.5, 1.4,...):

```
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% as.matrix %>% t() %>% as.vector()

  [1] "5.1"        "3.5"        "1.4"       
  [4] "0.2"        "setosa"     "4.9"       
  [7] "3.0"        "1.4"        "0.2"       
 [10] "setosa"     "4.7"        "3.2"       
 [13] "1.3"        "0.2"        "setosa"
 ....
[739] "2.0"        "virginica"  "6.2"       
[742] "3.4"        "5.4"        "2.3"       
[745] "virginica"  "5.9"        "3.0"       
[748] "5.1"        "1.8"        "virginica"
```