# Extract a single dplyr tbl_df row as a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

How can one extract a single row from a `tbl_df` as a vector?  Simple subsetting with `[]` brackets yields a 1-row `tbl_df`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- as_data_frame(mtcars)

dat[2, ]

Source: local data frame [1 x 11]

    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1    21     6   160   110   3.9 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
```

A similar problem to [Extract a dplyr tbl column as a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector), but with (I think) some different solutions.

Comment: ... or `unlist(dat[2,])`

Comment: Thanks both.  Turns out my question stems from not realizing that the product of `mtcars[2, ]` is a `data.frame`, as future operations I do to it like `paste(...)` coerce it to a vector.  I mistakenly thought it already was a vector.  Now I see I can also `paste(...)` onto a 1-row `tbl_df` and get a vector.  With that understanding, I think this is a duplicate.  Hope it will at least help others who are thrown off by seeing a `tbl_df`.  `unlist(dat[2, ])` is what I went with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Introduction to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html): "All of the dplyr functions take a data frame (or tibble) as the first argument." So no need to convert `mtcars` into a tibble. Furthermore, `as.numeric()` is more concise than `unlist(., use.names = FALSE)`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  slice(2) %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Comment: `as.numeric` is a nice option!  I think the `as_tibble` calls in akrun's answer are just to illustrate how it works on a `tbl_df`, since that was the focus of the question.

Answer (score 30):

Using the `dplyr` `%>%` operator

```
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(mtcars) %>%
           slice(2) %>% 
           unlist(., use.names=FALSE)
```

Or we can use `c` with `recursive=TRUE`

```
as_tibble(mtcars) %>%
          slice(2) %>% 
          c(., recursive=TRUE) %>%
          unname
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't
`as.numeric(mtcars[2,])`
be the simplest answer?

Comment: Yes. But some may argue that using pipes is more transparent. Others may prefer to avoid the Tidyverse dialect of R, and stick with base R, and would therefore be happiest with @andrewj's solution.