# Why does subsetting a column from a data frame vs. a tibble give different results

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

This is a 'why' question and not a 'How to' question.

I have a `tibble` as a result of an aggregation `dplyr`

```
> str(urls)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   144 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ BRAND       : chr  "Bobbi Brown" "Calvin Klein" "Chanel" "Clarins" ...
 $ WEBSITE     : chr  "http://www.bobbibrowncosmetics.com/" "http://www.calvinklein.com/shop/en/ck" "http://www.chanel.com/en_US/" "http://www.clarinsusa.com/" ...
 $ domain      : chr  "bobbibrowncosmetics.com/" "calvinklein.com/shop/en/ck" "chanel.com/en_US/" "clarinsusa.com/" ...
 $ final_domain: chr  "bobbibrowncosmetics.com/" "calvinklein.com/shop/en/ck" "chanel.com/en_US/" "clarinsusa.com/" ...
```

When I try to extract the column final_domain as a character vector here's what happens:

```
> length(as.character(urls[ ,4]))
[1] 1
```

When I instead, coerce to data frame and then do it, I get what I actually want:

```
> length(as.character(as.data.frame(urls)[ ,4]))
[1] 144
```

The `str` of the tibble vs. dataframe looks the same but output differs. I'm wondering why?

Comment: probably because `tbl_df ` and `data.frame` have different indexing properties. When you index one column from a `data.frame`, you get a `vector` but when you index one column from a `tbl_df`, you still get a `tbl_df`. Also, `length` returns the number of columns when given a `data.frame` and the number of rows when given a `vector`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The underlying reason is that subsetting a tbl and a data frame produces different results when only one column is selected.

- By default, `[.data.frame` will drop the dimensions if the result has only 1 column, similar to how matrix subsetting works. So the result is a vector.
- `[.tbl_df` will *never* drop dimensions like this; it always returns a tbl.

In turn, `as.character` ignores the class of a tbl, treating it as a plain list. And `as.character` called on a list acts like `deparse`: the character representation it returns is R code that can be parsed and executed to reproduce the list.

The tbl behaviour is arguably the right thing to do in most circumstances, because dropping dimensions can easily lead to bugs: subsetting a data frame usually results in another data frame, but sometimes it doesn't. In this specific case it doesn't do what you want.

If you want to extract a column from a tbl as a vector, you can use list-style indexing: `urls[[4]]` or `urls$final_domain`.

Comment: Perhaps add `dplyr::pull` as a way to extract a column as a vector (used now and then in pipes).

Answer (score 6):

I think the fundamental answer to your question is that Hadley Wickham, when writing *tibble* 1.0, wanted consistent behavior of the `[` operator. This decision is discussed, somewhat indirectly, in Wickham's *Advanced R* in the [chapter on Subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html):

> It’s important to understand the distinction between simplifying and
>   preserving subsetting. Simplifying subsets returns the simplest
>   possible data structure that can represent the output, and is useful
>   interactively because it usually gives you what you want. Preserving
>   subsetting keeps the structure of the output the same as the input,
>   and is generally better for programming because the result will always
>   be the same type. Omitting drop = FALSE when subsetting matrices and
>   data frames is one of the most common sources of programming errors.
>   (It will work for your test cases, but then someone will pass in a
>   single column data frame and it will fail in an unexpected and unclear
>   way.)

Here, we can clearly see that Hadley is concerned with the inconsistent default behavior of `[.data.frame`, and why he would choose to change the behavior in *tibble*.

With the above terminology in mind, it's easy to see that whether the `[.data.frame` operator produces a simplifying subset or a preserving subset by default is dependent on the input rather than the programming. e.g., take a data frame `data_df` and subset it:

```
data_df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = letters[1:10])

data_df[, 2]
data_df[, 1:2]
```

You get a vector in one case and a data frame in the other. To predict the type of output, you have to either know in advance how many columns are going to be subsetted (i.e. you have to know `length(list_of_columns)`), which may come from user input, or you need to explicitly add the `drop =` parameter. So the following produces the same class of object, but the added parameter is unnecessary in the second case (and may be unknown to the majority of R users):

```
data_df[, 2, drop = FALSE]
data_df[, 1:2, drop = FALSE]
```

With *tibble* (or *dplyr*), we have consistent behavior by default, so we can be assured of having the same class of object when subsetting with the `[` operator no matter how many columns we return:

```
library(tibble)
data_df <- tibble(a = runif(10), b = letters[1:10])

data_df[, 2]
data_df[, 1:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the result of `as.character`, you'll notice the difference:

```
library(tibble)
x <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y,  ~z,
    "a", 2,  3.6,
    "b", 1,  8.5
)

as.character(as.data.frame(x)[ ,2])
# [1] "2" "1"

as.character(x[ ,2])
# "c(2, 1)"
```

`as.character` converts the column to a single string. This thread should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector