# How to apply the diff function on a tibble

Tags: r

I want to apply a diff to a data frame column, accessing it by its name. What I do is the following:

```
abscissa <- "distance"
data.op[, abscissa]
```

I get this output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 1
   distance
        <dbl>
 1     0.0426
 2     0.0409
 3     0.0412
 4     0.0406
 5     0.0406
 6     0.0407
 7     0.0402
 8     0.0403
 9     0.103 
10     0.0402
11     0.0395
12     0.0407
13     0.0406
14     0.0405
15     0.0404
```

Then I simply try:

```
 diff(data.op[, abscissa])
```

But the output is:

```
 # A tibble: 15 x 0
```

I also tried `data.op[, abscissa] %>% diff` and `data.op %>% select(abscissa) %>% diff` with the same zero column result.

However, if I do

```
diff(as.data.frame(data.op)[, abscissa])
```

It works:

```
[1] -0.00169560  0.00024120 -0.00061200  0.00000000  0.00013320 -0.00045360  0.00003240  0.06299047 -0.06306967 -0.00071640  0.00120960 -0.00007920
[13] -0.00010440 -0.00005400
```

When I type `str(data.op)`, I get:

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 15 obs. of  28 variables:
...
```

What I don't understand is:

- Why is my data frame a tibble ? <s>Ok, I installed tidyverse, but I never used it on this data frame before.</s>

**Edit:** Not true, I did use `mapvalues()` function to create the data frame, so I guess it's why it is a tibble, not a simple data frame.

- My data.op is *also* a data frame, so why doesn't `diff(data.op[, abscissa])` work?
- Why `data.op[, abscissa] %>% diff` and `data.op %>% select(abscissa) %>% diff` don't work either?
- Do I really need to convert it to a data frame to make a simple diff? This doesn't help readability...

Sorry I can't provide a more reproducible example. I tried with mtcars and everything works as expected (but mtcars is a data frame, not a tibble). At some point, my data.op data frame was converted to a tibble, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Related: [Why does subsetting a column from a data frame vs. a tibble give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918774/why-does-subsetting-a-column-from-a-data-frame-vs-a-tibble-give-different-resul)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as.tibble(mtcars)
abscissa <- "mpg"
```

Now, when you do

```
diff(df[, abscissa])
# A tibble: 32 x 0
```

but

```
diff(mtcars[, abscissa])
#[1]   0.0   1.8  -1.4  -2.7  -0.6  -3.8  10.1  -1.6  -3.6  -1.4  -1.4   0.9
#[13]  -2.1  -4.8   0.0   4.3  17.7  -2.0   3.5 -12.4  -6.0  -0.3  -1.9   5.9
#[25]   8.1  -1.3   4.4 -14.6   3.9  -4.7   6.4
```

works fine.

That is because

```
class(df[, abscissa])
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

whereas

```
class(mtcars[, abscissa])
#[1] "numeric"
```

Now from `?diff`

> x - a numeric vector or matrix containing the values to be differenced

Hence, it does not work with tibbles.

You could do

```
df %>% pull(abscissa) %>% diff
# [1]   0.0   1.8  -1.4  -2.7  -0.6  -3.8  10.1  -1.6  -3.6  -1.4  -1.4   0.9
#[13]  -2.1  -4.8   0.0   4.3  17.7  -2.0   3.5 -12.4  -6.0  -0.3  -1.9   5.9
#[25]   8.1  -1.3   4.4 -14.6   3.9  -4.7   6.4
```

since

```
df %>% pull(abscissa) %>% class
#[1] "numeric"
```