# Why isn't df$VARNAME the same as df[,i] when reading data using the R haven package?

Tags: r, vector, r-haven

Context: I've read the PISA 2022 data using the `haven` package and now I want to create an auxiliary df that consists of three columns:

- variable name (e.g. EFFORT1)
- variable label (e.g. How much effort did you put into this test?"
- variable values (e.g. 1, 2, 3, ...)

The issue is that the label and values are accesible if I type `attributes(pisa_df$EFFORT1)`, but NOT if I type `attributes(pisa_df[,i])`. Why would this be, and is there a way to get around this? I have >1000 variables so typing them one by one is not an option. I've tried something like `pisa_df$get(colnames(pisa_df)[i])` but of course it doesn't work.

It seems like a very newbie question but I can't even figure out *how* to search for possible answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: haven can be a pain. Try `readstata13::read.dta13` or `foreign::read.spss` depending on your data format.

Comment: You include the [tag:atomic] tag, but `df[,i]` is not guaranteed to be atomic, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39918774/3358272 for an explanation on why `df[,i]` returns different things based on if `df` inherits `"tbl_df"` or `"data.table"` (in addition to inheriting `"data.frame"`).

Comment: @r2evans: is any of that related to what the [atomic] tag is about?  Indivisible operations such as database transactions, or in multi-threaded programs.  (Like C++ `std::atomic<int>` with operations like `atomic_fetch_add`.)  It seems R uses the term "atomic" for something entirely different (first google hit was https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-vectors-in-r-programming/ which says something about a vector having elements that are all the same type).  If SO has a tag for that, it's not [atomic].  Can [r] tag followers please fix the tags on questions that use incorrectly use [atomic]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, the reason that `attributes(pisa_df$EFFORT1)` works but `attributes(pisa_df[,1])` does not is because of [Why does subsetting a column from a data frame vs. a tibble give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39918774/3358272). Namely, in native R, `[.data.frame` when reducing to a single column drops to a vector, but `tbl_df` does not. The base `[` can choose to *not* reduce to a vector by adding the `drop=FALSE` argument.

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:3,]
mt[,1]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8
mt[,1, drop=FALSE]
#                mpg
# Mazda RX4     21.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0
# Datsun 710    22.8
tibble(mt)[,1]
# # A tibble: 3 × 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1  21  
# 2  21  
# 3  22.8
```

The workaround is to use `$` with names or `[[` with a column index,

```r
mt[[1]]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8
tibble(mt)[[1]]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8
```

In your case, working on a SAS file takes little effort to give what you want. Using the "school questionnaire file" (it was easy for me to get), we can do something like below.

Up front, I'm demonstrating grabbing the labels and unique values for a few columns. Some of the columns are all unique (e.g., `SCH` has 21,629 rows, and column `CNTSCHID` has 21,629 distinct values), so I'm not certain if that is as interesting to you. Regardless, while I'm choosing a few, you can use this for all of them without problem.

Also, some of the values are `character`, some are `numeric`, so we must either convert all numbers to strings, or we have two separate columns. I'll choose the latter for demonstration, as I think converting all to string would be simpler for you to adapt yourself.

```r
SCH <- haven::read_sas(unz("SCH_QQQ_SAS.zip", "cy08msp_sch_qqq.sas7bdat"))
library(dplyr)
columns <- c(1, 3, 4, 5)
quux <- lapply(columns, function(ind) {
  out <- tibble(column = names(SCH)[ind], label = attributes(SCH[[ind]])$label)
  if (is.character(SCH[[ind]])) {
    cbind(out, tibble(values_chr = unique(SCH[[ind]]))) 
  } else cbind(out, tibble(values_num = unique(SCH[[ind]])))
}) |>
  bind_rows() |>
  tibble()
quux
# # A tibble: 21,794 × 4
#    column label                    values_chr values_num
#    <chr>  <chr>                    <chr>           <dbl>
#  1 CNT    Country code 3-character ALB                NA
#  2 CNT    Country code 3-character QAZ                NA
#  3 CNT    Country code 3-character ARG                NA
#  4 CNT    Country code 3-character AUS                NA
#  5 CNT    Country code 3-character AUT                NA
#  6 CNT    Country code 3-character BEL                NA
#  7 CNT    Country code 3-character BRA                NA
#  8 CNT    Country code 3-character BRN                NA
#  9 CNT    Country code 3-character BGR                NA
# 10 CNT    Country code 3-character KHM                NA
# # ℹ 21,784 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The notion is that if a particular column is `character`, then you would use `values_chr` (for whatever work you're doing). If you choose only `character` columns, then you can forego the `if`/`else` and just put out `values` of the distinct strings.

This can be done without `dplyr` if needed, with just a little more effort.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of using glue::glue_collapse() to collapse the 'labels' into a single-element character vector, so this might make things easier.

Comment: Thks for the explanation about differences between attributes df$colname and df[, position]!

Comment: Yes, the explanation on those differences was super helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sample data (`dput` at the end):

```
> aux_df
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  EFFORT1 EFFORT2 OCOD1 OCOD2 OCOD3 PROGN   
    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
1      10      10 243   9412  9999  00080002
2       9       8 8189  9999  9999  00080001
3      10      10 9999  9999  9999  0008000
```

Let's create a tibble with names and labels for it with `purrr` `map`, `pluck` and `attr_getter`:

```
aux_labels <- map_dfr(
  colnames(aux_df), 
  \(x) tibble(
    column = x, 
    label = pluck(aux_df, x, attr_getter("label"))))
```

Names and labels output:

```
> aux_labels
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  column  label                                                                   
  <chr>   <chr>                                                                   
1 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment)
2 EFFORT2 How much effort would you have invested? (after cognitive assessment)   
3 OCOD1   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Mother                                        
4 OCOD2   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Father                                        
5 OCOD3   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Self                                          
6 PROGN   Unique national study programme code
```

Now, choose acolumn and merge it with the respective values:

```
aux_output <- cross_join(
  filter(aux_labels, column == "EFFORT1"), 
  select(aux_df, value = "EFFORT1"))
```

The output:

```
> aux_output
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  column  label                                                                    value
  <chr>   <chr>                                                                    <dbl>
1 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment)    10
2 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment)     9
3 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment)    10
```

If you want to make it to some (or all) columns at once, taking into account the possible different classes, you can try this:

```
# Choose some columns (or all: colnames(aux_df))
aux_columns <- c("EFFORT1", "EFFORT2", "OCOD1")

#
aux_output <- map_dfr(
  aux_columns,
  \(x) cross_join(
    filter(aux_labels, column == x), 
    aux_df %>% 
      select(value = x) %>% 
      mutate(value_class = class(value), value = as.character(value))))
```

The output:

```
> aux_output
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  column  label                                                                    value value_class
  <chr>   <chr>                                                                    <chr> <chr>      
1 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment) 10    numeric    
2 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment) 9     numeric    
3 EFFORT1 How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment) 10    numeric    
4 EFFORT2 How much effort would you have invested? (after cognitive assessment)    10    numeric    
5 EFFORT2 How much effort would you have invested? (after cognitive assessment)    8     numeric    
6 EFFORT2 How much effort would you have invested? (after cognitive assessment)    10    numeric    
7 OCOD1   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Mother                                         243   character  
8 OCOD1   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Mother                                         8189  character  
9 OCOD1   ISCO-08 Occupation code - Mother                                         9999  character
```

That's it. Here's the sample data's `dput`:

```
aux_df <- structure(list(
  EFFORT1 = structure(
    c(10, 9, 10), 
    label = "How much effort did you put into this test? (after cognitive assessment)"), 
  EFFORT2 = structure(
    c(10, 8, 10), 
    label = "How much effort would you have invested? (after cognitive assessment)"), 
  OCOD1 = structure(
    c("243", "8189", "9999"), 
    label = "ISCO-08 Occupation code - Mother"), 
  OCOD2 = structure(
    c("9412", "9999", "9999"), 
    label = "ISCO-08 Occupation code - Father"), 
  OCOD3 = structure(
    c("9999", "9999", "9999"), 
    label = "ISCO-08 Occupation code - Self"), 
  PROGN = structure(
    c("00080002", "00080001", "00080001"), 
    label = "Unique national study programme code")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```