# dplyr unnest_tokens not working

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, tidytext

I am loading one of the 5-core datasets from

[http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector)

using

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

config <- spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "2G"
sc = spark_connect(master = "local",config = config)
df=spark_read_json(sc = sc, name = "videos", path = "Path/to/reviews_Office_Products_5.json")
```

where one of the variables is a column of text reviews, likewise:

```
select(df,reviewText)
```

> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
>
> # Database: spark_connection
>   reviewText
>
> 1 I bought my first HP12C in about 1984 or so, and it served me faithfully until 2002 wh
>
> 2 "WHY THIS BELATED REVIEW? I feel very obliged to share my views about this old workhor
>
> 3 I have an HP 48GX that has been kicking for more than twenty years and an HP 11 that i
>
> 4 I've started doing more finance stuff recently and went looking for a good time-value-
>
> 5 For simple calculations and discounted cash flows, this one is still the best.  I used
>
> 6 While I don't have an MBA, it's hard to believe that a calculator I learned how to use
>
> 7 I've had an HP 12C ever since they were first available, roughly twenty years ago.  I'
>
> 8 Bought this for my boss because he lost his.  He loves this calculator & would not be
>
> 9 This is a well-designed, simple calculator that handles typical four-function math. La
>
> 10 I love this calculator, big numbers and calculate excellent so easy to use and make my
>
> # ... with more rows

I want to split the reviews into tokens, with each row containing a word, but that has proven to be difficult. When I try to use the function unnest_tokens, I get the following error message:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidytext) 

Word_by_Word <- df %>% unnest_tokens(word, reviewText)
```

> Error in unnest_tokens_.default(., word, reviewText) : 
>   unnest_tokens expects all columns of input to be atomic vectors (not lists)

What is happening? How do I fix this without using the command "pull" and coercing the data into the requested format? I can not pull the data as suggested in 
[Extract a dplyr tbl column as a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector) or convert the data to a tibble format, btw, because if the database is too big and I do any of those, then the computer runs out of memory even after increasing the 2G limit and running the program on a computer with a lot of memory (that's the hole point of using dplyr instead).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you already have the dataframe in memory. If so, then error code is pointing the way for you. Each entry in `reviewText` is a `list`, and `unnest_tokens()` expects them to be of class `vector`.

Try using `unlist()` to transform the `reviewText` field, either in-place or via `mutate()`.

Comment: when I try using `df %>% mutate(rt=unlist(reviewText))`, I get an error message saying that the function does not exist. Could you please be more specific as to how to use unlist?

Comment: `unlist()` is a base R function, so is the error in response to `mutate()`?

Comment: the error starts like this: `Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'UNLIST'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;`  I think the error might be caused because unlist is not a valid function for mutate.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The object `df` is not actually a dataframe in memory, but `spark_tbl` object? Can you use `sdf_mutate()` instead of `mutate()`?

Comment: Yes, `df` is a spark_tbl. I got the following error `Error in UseMethod("sdf_register") : 
  no applicable method for 'sdf_register' applied to an object of class "character"` after running `df %>% sdf_mutate(rt=unlist(reviewText))`