# Do I always have to unlist a dataframe/tibble before taking a column mean?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to use a pipe to take a mean of a column from some data in a package, and was surprised when I could not.

At first I thought it had to do with piping, but apparently it was because the df column needed to be unlisted before taking the mean. Is it possible to pipe data from a df/tibble directly to a mean function without de-listing first?

```
install.packages("UsingR")
library(UsingR)
library(dplyr)

father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  select(sheight) %>% mean

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

When I pipe all that into a new object and unlist it, I can take the mean; can I do that right from the pipe?

```
s <- father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  select(sheight)
mean(unlist(s))

> mean(unlist(s))
[1] 70.54082
```

Comment: `%>% unlist %>% mean`? Sure, you can do that. I think newer versions of `dplyr` have `pull`, which combines that functionality with selecting a column, so you can also do `mtcars %>% pull(mpg) %>% mean`.

Comment: Suggested dupe: [extract dplyr tbl column as a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21618423/903061)

Comment: I thought one could just operate on the col directly; I did not know about 'pull'. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, the point of dplyr is to keep everything in a data.frame, so why not just `father.son %>% 
    filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
    summarise_all(mean)`?

Comment: I guess you _could_ pipe directly into `colMeans`, though it returns a vector, breaking the dplyr paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to doing what Gregor suggests and piping everything though `unlist`, you can also stay in the `dplyr` framework and use `summarize`:

```
father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  summarize(mean(sheight))
```

Or use `$` to extract the data, in one of the three following ways:

```
father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  .$sheight %>% 
   mean

father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  `$`(sheight) %>% 
   mean

library(magrittr)
father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  use_series(sheight) %>% mean
```

Answer (score 3):

With the latest editions to `dplyr` there is a function to grab a column and return a vector, `pull`.

```
father.son %>% 
  filter(round(fheight) == 71) %>%
  dplyr::pull(sheight) %>% 
  mean
```