# Why does ggplot2 see a data.frame and data_frame differently?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have two very similar data frames, which `ggplot2` sees differently; although the contents are the same the data structures are subtly different. One is a `data.frame`, the other a `data_frame`. I'd like to understand the difference in how `ggplot2` sees them. In the following examples, both are being used in a `stat_function`; the `data.frame` produces plots while the `data_frame` produces errors. This is particularly confusing in light of the interoperability of packages in the Hadleyverse. I first ran into this issue when I found that I was unable to create a plot from a data frame produced by dplyr (dplyr turns data.frames into data_frames) while a data frame I thought was identical (it wasn't, it was a data.frame) worked just fine.

**Example 1**

First, the working version from the `data.frame`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d.f <- data.frame(mean = 0, sd = 1)
d_f <- data_frame(mean = 0, sd = 1)

ggplot(data.frame(x=-3:3), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) dnorm(x, mean = d.f[1,1], sd = d.f[1,2]))
```

[image: plot from data.frame]

And now the non-working version from the `data_frame`.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=-3:3), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) dnorm(x, mean = d_f[1,1], sd = d_f[1,2]))
## Warning message:
## Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
## Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

[image]

**Example 2**

This example produces a different error message though perhaps the underlying issue is the same. First, the working version with a `data.frame`.

```
logistic <- function (x) { 1/(1 + exp(-x)) }

d.f <- data.frame(b0 = -9, b1 = 0.8) 
d_f <- data_frame(b0 = -9, b1 = 0.8) 

ggplot(data.frame(x=0:20), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) logistic(d.f[1,1] + d.f[1,2] * x))
```

[image: plot produced from data.frame]

And here's the non-working version with a `data_frame`.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=0:20), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) logistic(d_f[1,1] + d_f[1,2] * x))
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

Comment: Try `pull(d_f[1,2])`. It's still a tibble after subsetting.but ggplot is expecting a vector which is `pull` fixing. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector)

Comment: It's not ggplot. The truth is that `data_frame`s are **not** `data.frame`s in some important respects, and you've discovered one of them. Hadley decided that he didn't like some of the default behavior of `data.frame`s and so he intentionally made `data_frame`s behave differently. User beware.

Comment: ...you can create the same error with `data.frame`s by doing `d.f[1,1,drop = FALSE]`, I think.

Comment: As other comments alluded to, see the different output from `d.f[1, 1]` and `d_f[1, 1]`.

Comment: `data_frames` are `data.frames`, they just don't return the same object when subsetted, with `data_frame` you need to be explicit of you want to change the class. `d_f[1,1]` is a `data_frame` (and thus a `data.frame` as well) in one case, and a numeric in the other.

Comment: I'm going to combine these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot` was seeing a data frame where it expected a value.

This resulted from differences between the data types returned by the subsetting square-bracket operator applied when applied to a `data.frame` or a `tibble` (the data frame preferred by Hadley's `dplyr`). Subsetting a `data.frame` can change types by default, e.g. returning a vector or value. Subsetting a `tibble` will return a `tibble` unless the user requests re-casting explicitly, e.g. by using `pull` or double-brackets `[[]]`. The error message "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function" should have been a clue.

The following code demonstrates this by appropriately re-casting the `tibble`s.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

```
d.f <- data.frame(mean = 0, sd = 1)
d_f <- data_frame(mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Subsetting a `tibble` (aka `tbl_df`) returns a `tbl_df`.

```
class(d_f[1,1])
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Which can be re-cast with double square-brackets `[[]]` or `pull`.

```
class(d_f[[1,1]])
## [1] "numeric"
class(pull(d_f[1,1]))
## [1] "numeric"
```

Subsetting a `data.frame` returns a numeric vector.

```
class(d.f[1,1])
## [1] "numeric"
```

The behavior of subsetting a `tibble`, i.e. no re-casting, can be produced with the argument `drop=FALSE`.

```
class(d.f[1,1, drop=FALSE])
## [1] "data.frame"
```

Finally, showing that resolving the type issue resolves the plotting issue ...

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=-3:3), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) dnorm(x, mean = pull(d_f[1,1]), sd = pull(d_f[1,2])))
```

and

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=-3:3), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) dnorm(x, mean = d_f[[1,1]], sd = d_f[[1,2]]))
```

both produce the expected plot.
[image: plot created when types are correct]