# Use $ dollar sign at end of of an R magrittr pipeline to return a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'd like to use `$` at the end of a `magrittr`/`tidyverse` pipeline.  `$` works directly next to `tidyverse` functions like `read_csv` and `filter`, but as soon I create a pipeline with `%>%` it raises an error.  Here is a simple reproducible example.

```
# Load libraries and create a dummy data file
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
write_csv(data_frame(x=c(0,1), y=c(0,2)), 'tmp.csv')

# This works
y <- read_csv('tmp.csv')$y
str(y)

# This also works
df_y <- read_csv('tmp.csv')
y <- filter(df_y, y > 0)$y
str(y)

# This does not work
y <- read_csv('tmp.csv') %>% filter(y > 0)$y
```

My questions are:

1) What are the underlying explanations/mechanics for why using `$` at the end of a pipepline does not work?

2) What's a best practice way for what I am trying to accomplish?  Specifically, to get a vector as the end result of a pipeline?

Comment: There's some overlap w/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423.  It doesn't address your question 1.  But it provides alternatives to the [`dplyr::pull()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2054) I advocated below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not work because it thinks that the function is `$`, not `filter`, and tries to run:

```
"$"(., filter(y > 0), y)
```

which, of course, makes no sense.

Suppose `DF` is as shown below.  Then any of the subsequent lines of code work as expected:

```
DF <- data.frame(y = seq(-3, 3))

DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>% "$"(y)
## [1] 1 2 3

DF %>% { filter(., y > 0)$y }
## [1] 1 2 3

DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>% "[["("y")
## [1] 1 2 3

library(magrittr) # supplies extract2 as an alias for [[
DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>% extract2("y")
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Nice answer! Also: `DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>% .$y`

Comment: Why is it `"$"(., filter(y > 0), y)` and not just `"$"(filter(y > 0), y)` ? What is the significance of 'dot' here?

Comment: Why `DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>% "$"(y)` works while `DF %>% filter(y > 0) %>%$y` doesn't?

Comment: The syntax `$y` is not syntax accepted by R.  Either use `sometthing$y` or else the usual function notation with parnetheses.

Answer (score 2):

question 1: I think the problem is grouping.  Enclose most of that statement in parentheses, and it produce the same result as your first two approaches:

```
y <- (read_csv('tmp.csv') %>% filter(y > 0))$y
```

question 2: the newish function [`dplyr::pull()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) is my preference for pulling out a single vector, instead of returning an entire data.frame.

```
read_csv('tmp.csv') %>% 
  filter(y > 0) %>% 
  dplyr::pull(y)
```

The older way was to treat the data.frame as a list, and pull out a single element.  The dot on the last line is magrittr syntax for the output of a pipe.

```
read_csv('tmp.csv') %>% 
  filter(y > 0) %>% 
  .[["y"]]
```