# Select observations in a column that meets a particular condition

Tags: r, percentile

I have an question that seems simple but is stumping me. My time series data looks like:

```
Year Percentile Value
1990 p.10 20
1990 p.50 30
1990 p.90 40
```

I am trying to select the Value observations that correspond to the 10th percentile (e.g., p.10).

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field)?

Comment: look at `dplyr::filter()`

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work because I'm not subsetting a dataframe, I'm subsetting a vector within dataframe, according to other vector's values in the dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

As Jan said, `dplyr::filter` is helpful for things like this.

`library(dplyr)
percentiledata <- dplyr::filter(data, Percentile == "p.10")`

Comment: The issue is that I don't want a subsetted dataframe as a result. I want a vector of the variable Value, that only contains Value observations for when the percentile is p.10.

Comment: @James We can use the `pull` function after the `filter` function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector).

Answer (score 0):

```
 subset(dat,grepl("10",Percentile))
  Year Percentile Value
1 1990       p.10    20
```