# How to use a piece of an object using a pipe

Tags: r, pipeline

From [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial#intro), I understand that pipes "take the output of one statement and make it the input of the next statement."

Can I select a *piece* of an output and make it an input of the next statement?
For example, I'd like to know where the outliers are in this dataset :

```
mtcars$mpg %>% boxplot()$outliers %>% which
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```mtcars$mpg %>% boxplot() %>%  `[[`("out")```

Comment: Load magrittr and use a dollar pipe `mtcars %$% mpg %>% boxplot %$% out`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21618423

Comment: @Frank amazing. I get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  lazy-load database` when loading `magrittr` tho

Comment: @M-M Hm, that's not good. Maybe retry in a new R session (and maybe also after reinstalling magrittr)?

Comment: @Frank Tried that already. That error has been with me for the past couple of weeks. I guess I should reinstall R altogether.

Comment: Btw, the nice tutorial OP links includes `%$%` starting under "Additional pipes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `purrr::pluck()`

```
mtcars$mpg %>% boxplot() %>% purrr::pluck("out")
```

depending on the output type of the function, you can also use `[`

```
mtcars$mpg %>% boxplot() %>% .[["out"]]
```